# how to use between operator in python?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I want to extract few records based on the some range of values say 1 to 10.
I established a odbc connection and tried using the below code.

```py
idstart = 1
idend = 10
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE Serial_Num >= %s AND Serial_Num <= %s", (idstart , idend ))
```

But it was reporting:
`ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')`

I saw that pandas read_sql is for sqlite. Is there any way of doing this for MS SQL SERVER.

Comment: Pandas `read_sql` is not just for SQLite.

Comment: The parameter marker is usually `%s` or `?` (depending on the package you're using). Not `%d`.

Comment: Yeah i tried using it as well but did not work

Comment: If `?` doesn't work either we need to see much more information to reproduce this problem. Like the exact library you import and how you created the cursor object (no actual connection details are needed though, don't put in your database hostname and password, just make names up for those).

Answer (score 3):

Different Python database drivers use different placeholders. While some use `%s` for unnamed placeholders, others use `?`:

```
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM test WHERE Serial_Num >= ? AND Serial_Num <= ?",
    (idstart , idend)
)
```

You'll need to consult the exact database driver's documentation for what style is used, or consult the [`<module>.paramstyle` attribute](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle).

Pandas `read_sql` is not just for SQLite, but if you are not using SQLite, then you *must* use SQLAlchemy to manage the connection. SQLAlchemy [supports Microsoft SQL server connections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html).

Comment: @Vamshi: then the placeholder style is different, and it probably wants `?`.

Comment: Yeah it is working with the placeholder. thanks Martjin!